# How can I completely delete mamp from my hard drive?

Tags: php, mamp

Mamp started acting up so i decided to delete and try a fresh install. I dragged the two mamp folders from my applications folder into the trash. After I did this I tried installing mamp again. the new mamp mysql wouln't start up so I turned off the apache on it went to localhost in my browser and php and apache are still working even tho i deleted them. I thoroughly searched my applications folder for any remaining traces of mamp and there are none. So just to make sure, I deleted the new mamp installs, created a file with phpinfo() function in it, and opened it in the browser under local host. The phpinfo displays. this is totally baffling. in the php info everything points to /Applications/MAMP. I've searched it several times and there is no mamp to be found in applications. Is there any way to delete this once and for all, possibly from the terminal? Does any body have any advice on how to solve this?

**Edit:** I've tried everything suggested so far and somewhere, somehow apache and mysql are still running. I'm verifying this by opening a .php file with a phpinfo() function in it. Iv'e searched the activity monitor for any sign of mysqld, php, or mamp, and there is nothing. When I open phpinfo, all the paths point to /Applications/MAMP, and /Applications/MAMPbin/php/php5.3.6/conf  etc.... I've look for these files and have even tried cd into them from the terminal and there's no trace of them. There is one path in particular that's kind of raising a red flag. It's the path to apache environment: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin 
that's the only one that's different from the rest. Since apache is required for php to run I'm thinking this path to apache has somehow got to be the cause of the problem. How can I further trouble shoot this?

Comment: this question belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com/, BTW a simple search could have fetched you the solution, check if this can help you http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/installation/uninstall , go though the official documentation if you are using just the MAMP.

Comment: also appzapper is a nice app for uninstallation on OSX. http://appzapper.com/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Using an uninstaller is going to be the most surefire way to restore your system to its former state, as mentioned in a comment to your post. Use that, but also check for the things I mention here, and take note of them in the future.

**/EDIT**

Check your activity monitor for php/mysql processes and once you find them, open terminal and type "killall ", without the < > around the process name.

It's worth noting that OS X already comes with Apache and PHP installed, which can be enabled by enabling "Web Sharing" in the System Prefs->Sharing. MySQL can easily be installed separately and linked to the PHP install.

Also, be sure to check ~/Library/Application Support and /Library/Application Support for other MAMP files.

Finally, be sure to check ~/Library/Preferences, /Library/Preferences, ~/Library/LaunchAgents, /Library/LaunchAgents, /Library/LaunchDaemons, and /System/Library/Extensions for third party extensions.

The above are basic cleanup methods, you probably won't have anything of concern in Extensions, for instance. However one thing is worth noting - Extensions (Kernel Extensions) can potentially wreak havock on your system. Ensure that you don't have any third party extensions that you don't NEED installed. You can see them by opening terminal and typing:

`kextstat | grep -v apple`

This will tell you the exact file names of third party extensions, which you can then process to delete inside the Extensions folder. It will require you to authenticate as superuser.

Restart your system when done.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Thus far, AppCleaner works beautifully for me. Try giving it a go.